# I can't connect paypal account with Mobile Payment Libraries

Tags: ios, paypal

I have a little problem with "Mobile Payment Libraries", I can't use paypal SDK because I'm not US developer.

I downloaded the iOS Mobile Payments Library SDK from PayPal. I created a developer account and try example test. This works.

I change "PayPalPayment recipient" for check if sandbox account received money. I run app, Paypal button is correctly appear but when I encode email and password for an other sandbox account, the connection button is disable. And this button stay in disable all time after that. This app was kill and uninstall from device and I download again "iOS Mobile Payments Library SDK" and run again, the connection button is already disable with no modification on paypal code.

Why the button is already disable?

Sorry for my english.

This is code call buy Button Paypal with my modification. But I don't things that this is the problem

```
- (void)simplePayment {
    [PayPal getPayPalInst].shippingEnabled = TRUE;
    [PayPal getPayPalInst].dynamicAmountUpdateEnabled = TRUE;
    [PayPal getPayPalInst].feePayer = FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER;

    PayPalPayment *payment = [[[PayPalPayment alloc] init] autorelease];
    payment.recipient = user.paypalAccount; //Sandbox account Email - Type:BUSINESS - Contry:US
    payment.paymentCurrency = @"EUR";
    payment.description = description;
    payment.merchantName = user.name;

    payment.subTotal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",(price * nb)]];

    payment.invoiceData = [[[PayPalInvoiceData alloc] init] autorelease];
    payment.invoiceData.totalShipping = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f€",type * nb]];

    payment.invoiceData.invoiceItems = [NSMutableArray array];
    PayPalInvoiceItem *item = [[[PayPalInvoiceItem alloc] init] autorelease];
    item.totalPrice = payment.subTotal;
    item.name = app.currentTicket.title;
    [payment.invoiceData.invoiceItems addObject:item];

    [[PayPal getPayPalInst] checkoutWithPayment:payment];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check in your log, maybe you have this message:
PayPalPayment not processable: At this time, 'USD' is the only currency code allowed.

At the moment you can't use EUR as currency, I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue. It is not active while you are pasting email/password. When you are typing it handly - it works for me.